# Help with partial derivative of a multivariate function

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, self-learning

I am reading about contrast functions as a generalized version of divergences from [this paper.](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.hmj/1206130775) There is a particular equation in page 17 that I cannot follow, even though it looks basic at the outset *- the math is self-contained on this page, no need to go over other pages  :)*. I will try and give the relevant equations here.

The contrast between two probability densities is defined as $$\rho\left(\boldsymbol{\theta}_{1}, \boldsymbol{\theta}_{2}\right)=\rho\left(f_{\boldsymbol{\theta}_{1}}, f_{\boldsymbol{\theta}_{2}}\right). \qquad(1)$$

We use the symbols $\varepsilon_{i}$ and $\delta_{j}$ for the partial differentials $\partial | \partial \theta_{1}^{i}$ and $\partial | \partial \theta_{2}^{j}$ respectively.

By definition of contrast function, $\rho\left(\boldsymbol{\theta}_{1}, \boldsymbol{\theta}_{2}\right)= 0$ when $\boldsymbol{\theta}_1 = \boldsymbol{\theta}_2$. Therefore, we have $$
\begin{array}{l}
\varepsilon_{i} \rho(\boldsymbol{\theta}, \boldsymbol{\theta})=0 \qquad (2)\\
\delta_{j} \rho(\boldsymbol{\theta}, \boldsymbol{\theta})=0 \qquad (3)
\end{array} 
$$

Next, the author claims that by differentiating equations  2 and 3, we obtain,  $$
\begin{array}{l}
\partial_{j} \varepsilon_{i} \rho(\boldsymbol{\theta}, \boldsymbol{\theta})=\varepsilon_{j} \varepsilon_{i} \rho(\boldsymbol{\theta}, \boldsymbol{\theta})+\varepsilon_{j} \delta_{i} \rho(\boldsymbol{\theta}, \boldsymbol{\theta})=0 \qquad (4)\\
\partial_{i} \delta_{j} \rho(\boldsymbol{\theta}, \boldsymbol{\theta})=\varepsilon_{i} \delta_{j} \rho(\boldsymbol{\theta}, \boldsymbol{\theta})+\delta_{i} \delta_{j} \rho(\boldsymbol{\theta}, \boldsymbol{\theta})=0 \qquad (5)
\end{array}
$$, where $\partial_{\boldsymbol{i}}=\partial / \partial \theta^{i}$.

Can you please explain how equations (4) and (5) follow from equations (2) and (3)?

**My attempt:**

Using the [total derivative formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative#The_chain_rule_for_total_derivatives), I get

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\partial_{j} \varepsilon_{i} \rho(\boldsymbol{\theta}, \boldsymbol{\theta})=\varepsilon_{j} \varepsilon_{i} \rho(\boldsymbol{\theta}, \boldsymbol{\theta})+ \delta_{j} \varepsilon_{i}  \rho(\boldsymbol{\theta}, \boldsymbol{\theta})=0 \qquad 
\end{array}
$$

Which is different from equation (4)

Comment: I don't buy equations 2 and 3 at all. partial derivatives are the derivatives holding all the other independent variables constant. By requiring $\mathbf \theta_1 = \mathbf\theta_2$, these are no longer independent variables. There is no such thing as your $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ partials anymore. There are only partials with respect to the components of $\mathbf\theta$, not $\mathbf\theta_1, \mathbf\theta_2$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair First differentiate, then evaluate. A contrast function is (by definition) non-negative and zero on the diagonal, so all its partials at any point on the diagonal are zero; this is why (2) and (3) hold.

Comment: Seems like a typo, but one of no consequence: $\delta_i$ and $\epsilon_j$ commute, and after switching $i$ and $j$ one recovers  the middle term of (4) from that of the correct formula you have. So both are 0.